# How to join tally dates with list of periods to retrieve wanted results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of tally dates that I want to combine with prices, but I want for results to have all the dates from tally and dates and price values from prices (and null prices when no periods correspond to tally date)

### Dates

```
Date
2017-12-22
2017-12-23
2017-12-24
2017-12-25
2017-12-26
2017-12-27
2017-12-28
2017-12-29
2017-12-30
2017-12-31
```

### Prices

```
periodstart periodend  price productID
2017-12-23 2017-12-25  50    1
2017-12-26 2017-12-29  10    1
```

Sql query result

```
date        price   productid
2017-12-22  null    1
2017-12-23  50      1
2017-12-24  50      1
2017-12-25  50      1
2017-12-26  10      1
2017-12-27  10      1
2017-12-28  10      1
2017-12-29  10      1
2017-12-30  null    1
2017-12-31  null    1
```

**UPDATE**
I added productID column in prices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rextester: http://rextester.com/ADJZSW20744

```
create table dbo.calendar (
    [date] date primary key clustered
);
insert into dbo.calendar values
 ('2017-12-22'),('2017-12-23'),('2017-12-24')
,('2017-12-25'),('2017-12-26'),('2017-12-27')
,('2017-12-28'),('2017-12-29'),('2017-12-30')
,('2017-12-31');

create table prices (
    periodstart date
  , periodend date
  , price int
  , productid int
);
  insert into prices values
  ('2017-12-23','2017-12-25',50,1)
  ,('2017-12-26','2017-12-29',10,1)
  ,('2017-12-22','2017-12-23',50,2)
  ,('2017-12-26','2017-12-27',10,2);
```

query: This will work with multiple products:

```
  select 
    c.Date
  , p.Price 
  , x.ProductId
  from dbo.Calendar c
    outer apply (
      select distinct 
          ProductId
        from prices
        ) x
    left join dbo.Prices p on 
          c.Date >= p.PeriodStart 
      and c.Date <= p.PeriodEnd
      and x.ProductId = p.ProductId
  order by x.ProductId, c.Date;
```

Comment: what about select 
    c.Date
  , p.Price, Products.productid 
  from dbo.Calendar c cross join (select distinct productid from prices) as Products
    left join dbo.Prices p on 
          c.Date >= p.PeriodStart 
      and c.Date <= p.PeriodEnd

Comment: @mko No need to cross join if it is on the prices table. Just add the column to the select.

Comment: Yes, but I will get productID null if dates are not matched, so that wont do it...

Comment: @mko Updated answer, and handles multiple products

Comment: Works great, but performance is not that difference between cross join and outer apply in this case....

Answer (score 1):

A simple left join should do the trick

```
Select A.Date
      ,B.Price
 From  Dates A
 Left  Join Prices B on A.Date Between B.periodstart and B.periodend
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Date
    , price
FROM Dates d
LEFT JOIN Prices p
ON d.Date BETWEEN p.periodstart AND ISNULL(p.periodend, d.Date)
```

To avoid conflicts in case your periods are intersecting or don't have an ending date, take the latest start period using an apply:

```
SELECT Date
    , price
FROM Dates d
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 price
    FROM Prices p 
    WHERE d.Date BETWEEN p.periodstart AND ISNULL(p.periodend, d.Date)
    ORDER BY p.periodstart DESC
) oa
```